# How to call Helper.php function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel, variables, helper

I have a function in helper.php:

```
public static function getFristImageSearch($slug)
{
    $slug = str_replace("-", " ", $slug);
    $image = Images::select('thumbnail')->where( 'metakeywords','LIKE', '%'.$slug.'%' )
    ->where('status', 'active' )
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->orderBy('DATE', 'desc' )
    ->first();
    if( isset( $image ) ) {
        return $image->thumbnail;
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

now I want to call this function in Javascript abc.js:

```
var n = e.replace(t, "<b>" + myvariable + "</b>");
var gotme = getFristImageSearch(n);
```

but variable `gotme` doesnot work

> getFristImageSearch is not defined

Comment: You should use AJAX request to get values from PHP function.

Comment: You have to call by using `route` name  method `AJAX`

Answer (score 1):

PHP code can't be run on JavaScript. They're completely separate here.

Based on your tags, I guess you're using Laravel.
You need to return your data as a [REST API endpoint](https://meritocracy.is/blog/2021/02/08/laravel-creating-restful-api-for-your-website/) with JSON data type.

Let's assume you've written an endpoint for the output of the function with this address: `/api/getFristImageSearch/slug`

Then you have to call it from your JavaScript side like this:

```
fetch(`'/api/getFristImageSearch/${slug}'`).then((response) => {
        // get your response data here
      })
```

You can use [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to fetch your data as well.

And if you're using this code in production, don't forget to [protect your routes](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-jwt-authentication-tutorial-user-login-signup-api/) if needed.